# how to solve this error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 OrElse IsNothing(DataGridView1.DataSource) OrElse DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim MBR As MsgBoxResult
    MBR = MsgBox("are you sure to delete it?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, Me.Text)
    If MBR = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Dim depobj As New ClassLib.departments
    depobj.id_dep = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("dep_id").Value
    If Not depobj.DeletefromDB() Then
        MsgBox("dont delete")
    End If

   RefreshMe()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = -1` actually be checking for 0? Set a breakpoint and check the value. If it is 0 then the code will continue, meaning that `depobj.id_dep = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("dep_id").Value` will try to access a row that is out of range

Comment: I did it but it go to the next step (exit sub) when i select the row in datagridview

Comment: So one of the other two conditions must be `True` then yes?

Comment: The row count can never be -1.  You are checking Row count at the start then acting on Selectedrows, what if there are no selected rows?